# improve snakemake rule in few aspects

Tags: python, list-comprehension, wildcard, snakemake, wildcard-expansion

I have a rule of which I use a loop in the `shell` parameter. Not sure if this is snakemake's best practice to utilize loops in the shell section. Perhaps someone could tell me whether or not this is the case.
I also produce many files from such rules but I was not able to leverage the wildcard properties of this rule. Here is the code:

```
def create_chrom():
    chroms = ['chr'+str(i) for i in range(1,23)]
    chroms.extend(['chrX','chrY']) 
    return chroms

rule split_by_chr:
    input:
        vcf = 'output/all_families.vcf.gz',
        vcf_idx = 'output/all_families.vcf.gz.csi'
    output:
        out = expand('output/by_chrom/all_families_{chroms}.vcf.gz',chroms=create_chrom())
    shell:
        'module load bcftools && '
        'bcftools index -s {input.vcf} | cut -f 1 | grep -w "^chr[1-9]\|^chr[1-9][0-9]\|^chr[X-Y]" | while read C; '
        'do bcftools view -O z -o output/by_chrom/all_families_${{C}}.vcf.gz {input.vcf} -r ${{C}}; done'
```

Notice that the function `create_chrom()` is producing a list of chromosome names and this list is being used in the `output` section, but not in the `shell` section.
I would like to know whether it is possible to use this list one element at a time on the shell section.

### Edit:

Would be greate to interpolate each item of the list returned by `create_chrom()` in this rule:

```
def create_chrom():
    chroms = ['chr'+str(i) for i in range(1,23)]
    chroms.extend(['chrX','chrY']) 
    return chroms


rule all:
    input: expand('output/by_chrom/all_families_{chroms}.vcf.gz',chroms=create_chrom())

rule split_by_chr:
    input:
        vcf = 'output/all_families.vcf.gz',
        vcf_idx = 'output/all_families.vcf.gz.csi'
    param:
        chroms = create_chrom()
    output:
        out = 'output/by_chrom/all_families_{chroms}.vcf.gz'
    shell:
        'bcftools view -O z -o {output.out} {input.vcf} -r {param.chroms}'
```

I'm aware that like this I'm passing the whole list, but I need to pass one chromosome at a time. i.e run once with `chr1` run again with `chr2` ... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that shell command produces specific-wildcard output, then the rule definition should contain the representation without expanding the wildcards:

```py
rule split_by_chr:
    input:
        vcf = 'output/all_families.vcf.gz',
        vcf_idx = 'output/all_families.vcf.gz.csi'
    output:
        out = 'output/by_chrom/all_families_{chroms}.vcf.gz'
    shell:
        """
        echo "{output.out}"
        # whatever is the appropriate command
        """
```

Then, to collect all the outputs, expand wildcards in the desired output using all variations into the default rule (typically `rule all`):

```py
rule all:
    input: expand('output/by_chrom/all_families_{chroms}.vcf.gz',chroms=create_chrom())
```

edit: to avoid defining function `create_chrom`, it's possible to pass explicit list of wildcard values to expand in rule `all` definition:

```py
list_chroms = ['chr'+str(i) for i in range(1,23)] + ['chrX','chrY']

rule all:
    input: expand('output/by_chrom/all_families_{chroms}.vcf.gz',chroms=list_chroms)
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand. I have the `rule all` like yours. `{output.out}` will expand the whole list of target files. I want to be able to pass one target output file at a time.

Comment: oh sorry, yes you are right.

Comment: The definition of rule `split_by_chr` is slightly different from the one in the question.

Comment: what about `create_chrom()` list, would it be possible to pass one at a time  to `shell` ?

Comment: if so I don't even need the loop anymore

Comment: I mean how could I leverage to use `bcftools view -O z -o {output.out} {input.vcf} -r ${{C}}` the chromosome name of each item of the list in `${{C}}` . I would like to get rid of the shell variable and use snakemake's wildcards

Comment: I'm not familiar with `bcftools`, so don't know what the input/output requirements are. Can you update the question with an example of what a correct shell call to `bcftools` would look like?

Comment: ok i edited, thanks. Let me know if it's unclear please

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like the problem is solved for you? From the updated question, one potential problem is that `params` can contain files that are not yet created. Not sure if that's OK for your command (`bcftools`) to contain nonexisting files, but it's possible.

Comment: yep solved I used `{wildcards.chroms}` and it worked .